# Python threading module creates user space threads or kernel spece threads

Tags: python

I was trying to use the `threading` module in Python. Now I have this query as to the type of threads that this module supports. That is whether these threads are user space threads or kernel space threads

Answer (score 6):

The correct term is not *kernel space thread* (because Python doesn't have access to kernel memory space), but *kernel-level threads*. `threading` module uses system-provided mechanisms (such as `pthread` on POSIX systems) which are usually relying on kernel interfaces (to create task via `clone(CLONE_THREAD)` on Linux).

Python supports *user-level threads* (those that are implemented purely in interpreter and occupy only one kernel-level thread) via generators, greenlets and similar libraries.

Comment: that means unlike pthread (which creates kernel space threads), Python threading module gives us user space threads

Comment: @user3282758: `threading` is most likely using `pthread` under the hood.

Comment: if pthread is used under the hood, then why dont we call them kernel space thread

Answer (score -1):

Short answer user space threads. 
Long answer from my knowledge of systems a process (or thread) is not user level or kernel level.

Some critical Tasks are are not directly accessible by the user eg memory and IO. To use these `resources` the kernel will expose `API's`.
These API's are better referred as `system calls` .
So your thread might br using those `system calls` in your program. But you cannot just spawn kernel threads

Comment: if I am using pthread library to create threads, then will these not be kernel-level threads

Comment: also I am not clear whether the Python threading module internally uses pthread_create whenever we create a new python thread or is it creating user-level threads